# how to keep React components mounted phase while switching between defrent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

bellow code makes component unmounted if state index changed

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
                  <TabScreens navigationState={this.state.index} onChangeTab={this.onChangeTab}>
                          {index==0&&<One/>}
                          {index==1&&<Two/>}
                          {index==3&&<Three/>}
                  </TabScreens>
  </View>
```

bellow code just hiding the component with display property none

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
                  <TabScreens navigationState={this.state} onChangeTab={this.onChangeTab}>
                          <One style={index==0?{display:'flex'}:{display:'none'}}/>
                          <Two style={index==1?{display:'flex'}:{display:'none'}}/>
                          <Three  style={index==2?{display:'flex'}:{display:'none'}}/>
                  </TabScreens>
</View>
```

second makes work but how can i achive this react logic is it possible  to write logic for this

and i also tried

```
React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)[0]/*index*/
```

or

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children,(cmp,iteration)=>{
    if(iteration==this.props.navigationState){
      return cmp;
}
})
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

> second makes work but how can i achive this react logic is it possible
>   to write logic for this

`display: none` is the way I hide components but keep them mounted. If you are attempting to do something more complex you may want to reference the documentation for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

You can write a function that returns the html you want. [Here is an example](https://alligator.io/react/modal-component/) tutorial for modals that conditionally shows `display: none`.

Your question is not very clear to me, but below is an example of how you can achieve this with logic outside of your render function using the documentation of conditional rendering.

```
const OpenTab = (props: {
  index: number;
}) => {
  switch(props.index)
    case 1:
    return (
      <>
      //.... whatever you want the code to look like
      </>
    );
    case 2:
    //.... more logic
  //....
};
```

Then you put

```
              <TabScreens navigationState={this.state} onChangeTab={this.onChangeTab}>
                <OpenTab index={index} />
              </TabScreens>
```

Comment: but while condiitonal rendrering component getting unmounting , how can i prevent component to be always mounted in that screen